# Easiest way to compare two database servers a replicate one after another?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have for example say: **P1** database, that I want to replicate into say **D1** database, how do I go about doing that in teradata using BTEQ script?

Comment: Same physical instance of Teradata or separate systems?

Comment: This was answered in your other question. ARCMAIN or TPT. Both Teradata utilities. BTEQ is not the appropriate tool for the task.

Answer (score 0):

The only way it could be done using `BTEQ` is to use `BTEQ` export from the source server and `BTEQ` import on the other one. Its a time consuming process and is not appropriate like @Rob Paller said above.